# Group similar rows and count groups in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I've got a table like this:

```
number | info | side
--------------------
     1 |  foo |    a
     2 |  bar |    a
     3 |  bar |    a
     4 |  baz |    a
     5 |  foo |    a
     6 |  bar |    b
     7 |  bar |    b
     8 |  foo |    a
     9 |  bar |    a
    10 |  baz |    a
```

I'd like to get how many times a `bar` group/package (e.g. rows 2,3 is a group, rows 6,7 is a group, row 9 is also a group) appears in the `info` column depending on `side`. I'm stuck because I don't really know what do google. Whenever I search for something like `group rows` or `merge rows` I always end up finding information about the `group by` feature.

However I think I need some kind of window function.

Here is what I'd like to achieve:

```
bar_a | bar_b
-------------
    2 |     1
```

Comment: `SELECT info, side, COUNT(info) FROM TABLE GROUP BY info, side`

Comment: Your quest is a bit unclear.  What happens if there are "bar"s next to each other with different "side"s?

Comment: Do you rely on a **gapless serial `number`**? Else, how to treat gaps? Can there be NULL values? (Would make concatenation and `<>` operator fail.) Your version of Postgres may be relevant (if too old). Do you need the result as *row* like demonstrated? And are you interested in all sides or just a selected set of sides?

Comment: I love asking SQL questions here. Answers are always top notch! Sorry I can't accept all of them. They are all great and helped finding a solution for my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `lag()` to determine first rows of groups:

```
select 
    number, info, side, 
    lag(info || side, 1, '') over (order by number) <> info || side as start_of_group
from my_table
order by 1;

 number | info | side | start_of_group 
--------+------+------+----------------
      1 | foo  | a    | t
      2 | bar  | a    | t
      3 | bar  | a    | f
      4 | baz  | a    | t
      5 | foo  | a    | t
      6 | bar  | b    | t
      7 | bar  | b    | f
      8 | foo  | a    | t
      9 | bar  | a    | t
     10 | baz  | a    | t
(10 rows)
```

Aggregate and filter the above result to get the desired output:

```
select concat(info, '_', side) as info_side, count(*)
from (
    select 
        info, side, 
        lag(info || side, 1, '') over (order by number) <> info || side as start_of_group
    from my_table
    ) s
where info = 'bar' and start_of_group
group by 1
order by 1;

 info_side | count 
-----------+-------
 bar_a     |     2
 bar_b     |     1
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a "gaps-and-islands" problem, at its heart, if I understand correct.  For this version, the difference of row numbers should work well.

```
select sum( (side = 'a')::int) as num_a,
       sum( (side = 'b')::int) as num_b
from (select info, side, count(*) as cnt
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (order by number) as seqnum,
                   row_number() over (partition by info, side order by number) as seqnum_bs
            from t
           ) t
      where info = 'bar'
      group by info, size, (seqnum - seqnum_bs)
     ) si;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make do with a *single* window function, which should be the fastest option:

```
SELECT side, count(*) AS count
FROM  (
   SELECT side, grp
   FROM  (
      SELECT side, number - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY side ORDER BY number) AS grp
      FROM   tbl
      WHERE  info = 'bar'
      ) sub1
   GROUP BY 1, 2
   ) sub2
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;  -- optional
```

Or shorter, maybe not faster:

```
SELECT side, count(DISTINCT grp) AS count
FROM  (
   SELECT side, number - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY side ORDER BY number) AS grp
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  info = 'bar'
   ) sub
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;  -- optional
```

The "trick" is that adjacent rows forming a group (`grp`) have consecutive numbers. When subtracting the running count over the partition on `side` from the running count over all rows (`number`), members of a "group" get the same `grp` number.

If there are **gaps in your serial column** `number`, which is not the case in your demo but typically there are gaps (and you actually want to ignore such gaps?!), then use `row_number() OVER (ORDER BY number)` in a subquery instead of just `number` to close the gaps first:

```
SELECT side, count(DISTINCT grp) AS count
FROM  (
   SELECT side, number - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY side ORDER BY number) AS grp
   FROM  (SELECT info, side, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY number) AS number FROM tbl) tbl1
   WHERE  info = 'bar'
   ) sub2
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;  -- optional
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8db898/3) (with extended test case)

Related:

- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35380/select-longest-continuous-sequence/35389#35389)